# Finding all combinations of vowel replacements

Tags: python, string, list, combinations

I am trying to find all possible combinations for all vowels in a word. So for example given 'hello':

`[halla, halle, halli, hallo, hallu, hella, halle, halli, hallo, hallu...]`

I have written the following function which will just take each vowel, and at each vowel, it will just replace it all with the vowels and add each version into a list. I'm trying to change that into the permutation as I want but it's not working. I tried inserting vowels("".join(string), arr) after the append but that results in infinite recursion.

```
def vowels(word, arr=None):
    if arr is None:
        a = []

    for i, c in enumerate(word):
        if c in 'aeiou':
            for v in 'aeiou':
                string = list(word)
                string[i] = v
                arr.append("".join(string))
    return arr
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: `if arr is None: a = []` should be `if arr is None: arr = []`. Is that a typo or is that your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once the typo CristopheD mentioned is fixed, your function returns this:

```
['hallo', 'hello', 'hillo', 'hollo', 'hullo', 'hella', 'helle', 'helli', 'hello', 'hellu']
```

... so it's returning some of the possible combinations, but not all of them.

That's because it's taking each vowel in the word in turn, and replacing it with each vowel in turn, then moving on to the next vowel in the word - but *not* taking into account the previous vowel(s) it found when it hits subsequent ones. Here's a recursive solution which works for words with any number of vowels:

```
import re

VOWELS = "aeiou"
RE_VOWEL = re.compile("[%s]" % VOWELS)

def helper(parts):
    if len(parts) == 1:
        yield parts[0]
    else:
        for vowel in VOWELS:
            for item in helper([vowel.join(parts[:2])] + parts[2:]):
                yield item

def vowels(word):
    parts = re.split(RE_VOWEL, word)
    return list(helper(parts))
```

Comment: Provided you don't run into the recursion limit ;-)

Comment: If this were a real world problem, I'd be less worried about the recursion depth (which is the number of vowels + 1, unless I'm mistaken) than the memory use ... were there a word containing a hundred vowels, that'd be well within Python's recursion limit, but would return a list on the order of 10^60 terabytes in size :-)

Comment: Well stated.  I concede.  (Clearly I didn't think through my comment as much as you did.  +1 for your efforts :)